# Can't add Microsoft.Azure.Cdn service principal to Key Vault access policies

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I cannot add Microsoft.Azure.Cdn service principal to Key Vault access policies.

I have run the following command in PowerShell.

```
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
```

I got the following result.

```
Secret: System.Security.SecureString
ServicePrincipalNames : {xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx, 
    https://microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/yyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyy}
ApplicationId: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx
DisplayName: Microsoft.Azure.Cdn
Id: zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzz
AdfsId:
Type: ServicePrincipal
```

Then I went to the Access Policies of the Key Vault to add the principal there but I can't find it in the list.

**Update**

When I try to add it I get this result.
[image]

But when I do the following that was suggested in a comment:

"First, navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> Enterprise applications -> filter with All applications -> search for the ApplicationId in your result, make sure the service principal is existing."

Then I get no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> filter with `All applications` -> search for the `ApplicationId` in your result, make sure the service principal is existing.

In the `Add access policy` page, search for the `Id` in your result(i.e. the `Object ID` of the SP), it should work.

[image]

Or you could use [`Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to add a service principal to the access policy, the `-ObjectId` is the `Id` in your result.

Sample:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ObjectId 34595082-9346-41b6-8d6b-295a2808b8db -PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set
```

**Update**:

Follow the steps as below.

Navigate to your keyvault in the portal -> copy the `Directory ID` and `Subscription ID`.

[image]

Login with `Connect-AzureRmAccount -TenantId "<Directory ID>" -Subscription "<Subscription ID>"`, use the two properties above.

If you already logged in, just use `Set-AzureRmContext -Tenant "<Directory ID>" -SubscriptionId "<Subscription ID>"`.

Then use the `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"` to create the service principal, when you create it successfully, navigate to the `access polices` in your keyvault to try to add it again.

Comment: Thanks, but when I search for the ApplicationId I get no result.

Comment: @Danied Did you filter with `All applications`?

Comment: Yes I filtered with that

Comment: @Danie If so, it means the service principal does not exist. Could you make sure you created the service principal in the correct tenant?

Comment: I updated my question with an image that shows that it seems like it already exist.

Comment: @Danie I know that, I mean could you use `Get-AzureRmContext` to check your context? than use `Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -Tenant "xxxxxx"` again to make sure you are in the correct tenant.

Comment: I was in the wront tenant. I used the cloud shell from the menu in the azure portal to make sure it was correct. Then it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is by using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

First check you are working with the right subscription by following below steps:

Login to Azure

```
az login
```

Get a list of your subscriptions

```
az account list --output table
```

Set a subscription from the list to be the current active one

```
az account set --subscription "<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>"
```

Now copy the Service Principal ID shown in the blue box when you enable the "Custom Domain HTTPS" option

[image]

Create the Service Principal using that id

```
az ad sp create --id "d4631ece-daab-479b-be77-ccb713491fc0"
```

Go to your "KeyVault/Access Policies" and Add a new Access Policy

[image]

Grant "Get" and "List" permissions for the "Secret" and Select the Principal recently created

[image]

Do not forget to save your changes

[image]

You are done! You can now enable your "Custom Domain HTTPS" option and use your KeyVault.

Comment: principal name was changed to "Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-Cdn"