# Azure Service Principle Creation failing while configuring Harness Cost management report

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-billing, azure-cost-calculation

I am configuring Harness Cost Management report for my Azure Dev subscription and getting the below error while creating the service principle.

> When using this permission, the backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant

Used below command to create Service Principle.

```
az ad sp create --id 0211763d-24fb-4d63-865d-xxxxxxxxx
```

Here is the Harness link I am following for this setup
https://docs.harness.io/article/7idbmchsim-set-up-cost-visibility-for-azure

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have the error message from Azure cli>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the above issue ,You may refer the below workaround

- Make sure that CCM has been enabled properly as shown in the given DOC.

---

> After enabling CCM, it takes about 24 hours for the data to be
> available for viewing and analysis.

---

- Also make sure that you have the Application Administrator role assigned for your Azure AD and select the correct subscription where you need to create .
- As you are using `az ad sp create --id 0211763d-24fb-4d63-865d-xxxxxxxxx` instead of that use below [***`cmdlts`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create) to create Service principle .

`az ad sp create --id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

For more information please refer this [***Blogpost***](https://ngdocs.harness.io/article/v682mz6qfd-set-up-cost-visibility-for-azure), & refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004010/creating-service-principal-for-azure-cdn-is-failing-with-tenant-permission-error) for similar error.